# Calculate $1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + n^n$

Tags: power-series, exponentiation

Is there a formula to calculate
$1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + n^n$

I searched but didn't find a formula for increasing powers

Comment: I am not aware of any such formula, but you can find an asymptotic expansion as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: If $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^k$, then $a_{n+1}/a_n \rightarrow e\cdot n$.